# how to permanently edit coredump_filter file and apply immediately without reboot?

Tags: linux, bash, linux-kernel, coredump

is there any way to permanently edit **coredump_filter** file and apply immediately without reboot.

temporary I can do like

```
echo 0x0 > /prod/self/coredump_filter
```

but this for current session only. i want to make this permanent and for everyone.
is there any way to do this?

Comment: read https://linux.die.net/man/5/sysctl.conf https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-sysctl.service.html https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sysctl.d.html#

Comment: I'm a little confused why there is no reply. If you have any problem of the answer, please tell me so that we can improve it. If it's helpful to you, can you please give me a useful upvote or acception? That's important for me

Comment: once i will try and if it fix my issue then definitely will accept.

Answer (score 0):

Can this works?

```
sysctl -w /prod/self/coredump_filter 0x0
sysctl -p
```